# How to make (make-symbol "foo") (make-symbol "foo") equal?

Tags: symbols, equality

I'm curious why:

```
(equal (make-symbol "foo") (make-symbol "foo"))
```

ends up beeing `nil`.

While

```
(equal 'foo 'foo)
```

is `t`.

Do i have a misconception of symbols?
Aren't they just strings without double-quotes?

Comment: I don't know why you're comparing lists with a single symbol inside in your second example.

Comment: I can't tell you, either. I changed it :P.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Do i have a misconception of symbols? Aren't they just strings without double-quotes?

You do indeed have a misconception.

A symbol is a lisp object containing numerous properties (including its name, its variable/value slot; and its function slot; but you can in fact set arbitrary properties on them, and many symbols have more than just the above).

A symbol (object) can be *referred to in code* with a textual name (in which case the lisp reader *interns* that text to obtain the canonical symbol of that name); so you will usefully improve your understanding of Lisp if you understand that a symbol is not its name, but rather that the name is just a way of accessing a more complicated object<sup>1</sup>.

Furthermore, it is entirely valid (and useful) to be able to have more than one symbol with a given name, and `make-symbol` facilitates this by returning a *new, un-interned* symbol.  Therefore it is expected and necessary that `(equal (make-symbol "foo") (make-symbol "foo"))` is `nil`, as you are comparing two independent objects (both of which happen to have the name "foo" -- and neither of which is the canonical symbol `foo`).

However most of the time you do actually want to obtain the *single, canonical* symbol of a given name, and this is what `intern` gives you:

```
ELISP> (eq 'foo (intern "foo"))
t
```

For more details, see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Creating Symbols` <kbd>RET</kbd>

---

<sup>1</sup> Beyond this you will at some point want to understand what the *lisp reader* is doing in general, and the different things which are being processed in the "read" vs "eval" phases of lisp execution.  In brief, the "read" phase converts the code (text) you write into lisp objects, and the "eval" phase works on those objects (rather than on the text that you wrote).  You don't necessarily *need* to know this, but certain things may fall into place more easily later on if you're at least vaguely aware of this distinction.

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing `make-symbol` and `intern`.  `make-symbol` is used specifically when you want such an equality not to hold.