# How to access variables/lists by the strings of their names, prompted interactively

Tags: interactive, symbols

I have a question about how to use `interactive` to allow the user to identify a desired list element to output.

Let's say I have a variable `x` assigned to a list structured like this:

```lisp
(setq x '((y ("y1")
             ("y2")
             ("y3"))
          (z ("z1")
             ("z2")
             ("z3"))))
```

If I want to retrieve the text "(y1)" from this structure and show it to the user, I know that I can do so by using:

```lisp
(message (format "%s" (nth 1 (assoc 'y x))))
```

The problem comes when I try to do the same thing interactively. Let's say I want to write a function that asks the user for the variable name and the desired list (y or z), then retrieves the first associated element:

```lisp
(defun find-first-associated-value (varname listname)
  (interactive
   "sWhich variable? :
sWhich list? :")
  (message (format "%s" (nth 1 (assoc listname varname)))))
```

If I try to call this function and fill in the right values, I get the error `Wrong type argument: listp, "y"`.

I can tell the reason this isn't working is that I'm passing strings (`varname` and `listname`) to `assoc`, which expects a KEY and then VALUE. The problem is that I can't figure out how to convert the user-inputted strings collected by `interactive` to those forms so that they can be understood by `assoc`. How can I fix this? I'd be very grateful for any help, and I apologize if the question is poorly worded--I'm new to programming in Lisp.

Comment: The problem is that the user inputs the string "y", but your list is using the *symbol* `y`.  You could try to convert the user inputted string with its symbol via [`make-symbol`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html).

Comment: @Dan I expect you meant `intern` ?

Comment: elisp tag doesn't apply here. Please, read [elisp tag](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(interactive "S")` to obtain a symbol instead of a string.

Regarding your general question, `(intern STRING)` returns the canonical symbol with the given name.

`(eq 'foo (intern "foo"))`
=> `t`

For more information, see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Creating Symbols`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/39351/454 might be helpful as well.

Comment: Although this isn't the case, using `make-symbol` (uninterned symbols) helps to avoid name collision. It's implicit in the previous comment link and Dan's original comment but only briefly mentioned in the docs (AFAIK).

Comment: Thank you so much for this - it's great to know about `format` (and `make-symbol`). I've tried to incorporate your recommendations into my code, but I must have misunderstood something, because I'm still getting the same error - whether I use `"S"` instead of `"s"` in `interactive` or `(nth 1 (assoc (intern listname) varname)))`, it comes out as `Wrong type argument: listp.` I'm going to keep reading and experimenting and see if I can ask a pertinent question.

Comment: I think you need to intern `varname` as well.