# Void variable when defining macro containing defvar in progn

Tags: elisp-macros, symbols

I don't understand why I get `(void-variable test-map)` when trying to run:

```
(defun something--key-map (name)
  (make-symbol (concat (symbol-name name) "-map")))

(defmacro defsomething (name)
  `(progn
     (defvar ,(something--key-map name) (make-sparse-keymap))
     (message "key map %s" ,(something--key-map name))))

(defsomething test)
```

When I try to `(macroexpand '(defsomething test))` I get `(progn (defvar test-map (make-sparse-keymap)) (message "key map %s" test-map))`, which when I paste it to scratch buffer, it is working. Do you know why it is not working directly?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39351 might be useful too.

Comment: Is it good idea to do those changes, if anybody in the future will have same problem as me, defvar would not work in his macro, he will never find this question and answer to it and in previous comment is already link to question that directly asks about source of this problem. Would not it be better to revert those changes, what do you think? @shynur

Comment: previous comment fyi @Drew

Comment: @tino415: You're right. I thought extracting the crux (*Symbols With a Same Name Are Not Equal*) of this question is better, but such a question already exists, so it's a good idea to edit it in order to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### Update (important)

To recognize *uninterned* symbols easily, set `print-gensym`:

```lisp
(defmacro mac ()
  (let ((a (make-symbol "taffy"))
        (b (make-symbol "taffy")))
    `(eq ',a ',b)))

(macroexpand '(mac))
;; => (eq 'taffy 'taffy)

(let ((print-gensym t))
  (macroexpand '(mac)))
;; => (eq '#:taffy '#:taffy)
```

---

`C-h f make-symbol`:

> Return a **newly allocated uninterned symbol** whose name is `NAME`.  
> Its value is ***void***, and its function definition and property list are `nil`.

So

```lisp
(let ((a (make-symbol "taffy"))
      (b (make-symbol "taffy")))
  (eq a b))
;; => nil
```

---

###### A:

Your `defvar`ed `test-map` is not the same symbol as the `test-map` you passed to `message`.  Emacs allocates memory for them separately, thus of course not `eq`.

And the latter's value is *void* since it isn't `defvar`ed.

---

You didn't ask how to implement what you want, but I guess you want to know.

Replace `make-symbol` with `intern`.  (`C-h f intern` for details.)